# How save, on a log file, all IP inbound/outbound connected to my Mac under MacOsX 10.9.5?

Tags: ip, macos

During its operation, the computer connects and disconnects to and from numerous servers - which are identified by a specific IP address.

Is there a solution to trace the ip addresses of all the input / output connections that occur every day with relative date and time and quantity of packets sent or received and saving them automatically on a log?

I know that there are products like WireShark that provide every single byte of each package, but I'm interested only in knowing the IP addresses that generated transactions.

Answer (score 1):

A log file of connections can easily be generated by a logging rule for your packet filter of choice on a Unix system.

For Mac OS, I think that is [`ipfw`](https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/6.1-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html).

Feel free to chose a tutorial of your liking on how to configure ipfw to generate the logs you specifically want - or ask a more refined question that details what exactly you want to have logged over at [SU](https://superuser.com) or another more appropriate stack exchange site that focuses on application questions like Unix or Mac OS.

Comment: Thank you, I will check and I will report the result asap.